# How do I access the data from Cloud Firestore database in Firebase using Swift in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase and basically I want to access the elements in the documents that are the **id** fields in each of the documents and I want to loop through them, is there any way I can retrieve and put that data in some kind of array and later loop through the array in swift? I am new here in StackOverflow please don't mind if I didn't ask the question properly. 
The link to the image how my database looks like is below please go through it.

[So this is how my CloudFirestore Database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySdi3.png)

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Are you trying to read the id field within each document? If so, that's pretty well covered in the Getting Started guide [Get multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection). Maybe if you clarify the question and include some code you've attempted, we'll better understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For This you have to setup Firebase Client SDK 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk
and after successfully setup

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("UniqueId's").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                    if let id = document.data()["id"] as? String {
                    //Here you'll get your data
                }
            }
```

By the way I think your collection name may be a problem So if it is than change it's name to UniqueIds instead of UniqueIds

Comment: Admin SDK is used when admin tasks are also required. For simple read/write Firebase Client info is enough.